# convert "this" keyword from as2 to as3

Tags: actionscript-3, this, actionscript-2

I am very new in actionscript 3 I have a problem to convert "this" keyword from as2 to as3.
please help me!

thanks !

My as2 code is:

```
var selected = MovieClip(null);
j = 1;
while (j++, j <= 11)
{
    var obj_1 = this["shape" + j];
    obj_1.highlight._visible = false;
    obj_1.onPress = function()
    {
        if (_root.selected)
        {
            _root.selected.highlight._visible = false;
        }
        // end if        
        this.highlight._visible = true;
        _root.selected = this;
        trace(this)
    };
}// end while
```

and my as3 code is:

```
var selecteD = MovieClip(null);

    var j:int = 1;

while (j < 11)
{
    j++;
    var obj_1:MovieClip = this['shape' + j];
    //trace(obj_1);
    obj_1.highlight.visible = false;
    obj_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressed);
    function pressed(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        if (MovieClip(root).selecteD)
        {
            trace(MovieClip(root).selecteD);

            selecteD.highlight.visible = false;
        }

        MovieClip(root).selecteD = **this**;
        MovieClip(root).selecteD.highlight.visible = true;

    }
}
```

when i trace this the result come Object main timeline in as3
but in as2 it is the level0.shape11

how could i convert "this" for this project.

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in as2 `this` refers to the object you add the `onPress` function to, `obj1`.
in as3 `this` refers to the class/object the function is defined in, in this case your main timeline. in as3 you can get the clicked object from the `MouseEvent`

```
while (j < 11)
{
    j++;
    var obj_1:MovieClip = this['shape' + j];
    //trace(obj_1);
    obj_1.highlight.visible = false;
    obj_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressed);
    function pressed(event:MouseEvent):void
    {


        if (MovieClip(root).selecteD)
        {
            trace(MovieClip(root).selecteD);

            selecteD.highlight.visible = false;
        }

        var clickedObject:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
        MovieClip(root).selecteD = clickedObject;
        MovieClip(root).selecteD.highlight.visible = true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#this) words it well:

> A reference to a method's containing object. When a script executes, the `this` keyword references the object that contains the script. Inside a method body, the `this` keyword references the class instance that contains the called method.

It's important to note that [`Function.call()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#call%28%29) and [`Function.apply()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29) are still present in AS3, which can alter the expected value of `this` in some instances.